# How to assign more than one value to a key in Object.assign

Tags: javascript

I am using Object.assign method to change the structure of my JSON.

```
  let opVal = []
  data[item].map(function(key,value) {
      opAllVal = key;
      finalResult = Object.assign(data, {[item]: [opAllVal]});
    });
```

Here `data` contains the JSON. And `key` contains more than one value at a time. I want to send all the values that are coming in `key` in the below format.
For e.g., If `item` is `sampleKey` and values in `key` are `sampleValue1` and `sampleValue2`, so they should be sent as -

```
"sampleKey":["sampleValue1","sampleValue2"]
```

but with the above code, these are sending as -

```
"sampleKey":["sampleValue2"]
```

Only the last value is getting sent everytime, not all the values which are coming in `key`. Can anyone help me in sending all the values of `key` to `item` in the above format.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Every time you use the code `finalResult = Object.assign(data, {[item]: [opAllVal]});`, you are overwriting the previous version of `data[item]` ignoring the previous content, in other words, `data[item]` is always set to an array with a single element that is `key`.

Btw, by the code it's not very clear what you'd like to do. If I understood you can have an input like this:

```js
data = {
    ... //other params
    "sampleKey": [
        "sampleValue1",
        "sampleValue2"
    ]
}
```

What's the expected output?

For what I see in the code it will be better to use `forEach` instead of `map` and the name of the variables in forEach should be inverted `(value, key)` instead of `(key, value)` as `map` and `forEach` call both the callback by passing before the value and after the key.

Also I suggest to change the tag in your question as it is not related to `reactjs` but it's related to js and independent from react (if you do this you'll receive more visualisations and more answers).